# Complex Excel Formula or VBA needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a 2x daily report I need to run which creates a potentially large Excel table of student data. Lots of columns in this report, but here are the ones I care about:

- Column A is a unique student ID
- Column C is a date.
- Column G is a class period.

This report lists the periods where attendance WAS taken on a given day or in a given date range. But I’m supposed to ascertain when attendance WASN’T taken.

Ideally, on Monday-Thursday in the report there should be Periods 1-6 (inclusive) listed for each student. (No periods 7 & 8).

On Friday in the report there should be Periods 7 & 8 only for each student. (No periods 1-6).
(The report maybe be run for a single day, or multiple day range).

Currently the report seems to regurgitate the data in random order, so I do a nested sort in Excel to make it palatable.

```
Example (after sort): (ID, date, period) in each row
8124577 11/11/2020 1
8124577 11/11/2020 3
8124577 11/11/2020 4
8124577 11/11/2020 6
8124577 11/12/2020 2
8124577 11/12/2020 4
8124577 11/12/2020 5
8124577 11/12/2020 6
8124577 11/13/2020 7
567435 11/11/2020 2
567435 11/11/2020 3
567435 11/11/2020 4
567435 11/11/2020 6
567435 11/13/2020 8
```

So my little (old!) human eye notices the following:

- Student #8124577 is missing period 2 & 5 on 11/11/2020
- Student #8124577 is missing period 1& 3 on 11/12/2020
- Student #8124577 is missing period 8 on 11/13/2020 (which is a Friday)
- Student #567435 is missing periods 1 & 5 on 11/11/2020
- Student #567435 is missing period 7 on 11/13/2020 (a Friday)

The School Administration wants me to just eyeball the 2x/day report data for 100+ students, is there a formula or another method I can use for this ?

Can anyone steer me the right way?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User please [Edit] your post & add some screen shot along with expected result and the formula/VBA code you have tried so far, will help us to suggest the better one!

Comment: I think it could be as simple as adding a fourth column (maybe called attended) that should be filled with 1's all the way down. Then create a pivot table with date/student id as rows (or put the date in the filter section) and periods as column, and finally the attended column as the values. This should give you a nice table that will show empty cells where students did not attend. Another benefit is that it should show possible data inconsistencies (like if you saw a 2 in the data section of the report). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into Power Query and, (you know what they say about a man with a hammer) here is a method using it:

- Sort the rows *(you can do it here from the original data)*
- Group the rows by `ID` and `Date` retaining `All Rows`
- Create a **List** of the periods marked for each ID/Date combination
- Test that list against another list for either `{1..6}` if the weekday number is `1 to 4`, or `{7,8}` if the weekday number is `5`, returning the missing values
- Split the list of missing values into a semicolon separated string

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"date", type date}, {"period", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"ID", "date"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [ID=nullable number, date=nullable date, period=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Periods Actual", each Table.Column([Grouped],"period")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Periods Missed", 
        each if Date.DayOfWeek([date]) >= 1 and 
                Date.DayOfWeek([date]) <= 4 then 
            List.Difference({1..6}, [Periods Actual]) else 
              if Date.DayOfWeek([date]) = 5 then 
            List.Difference({7,8},[Periods Actual]) else 
                "invalid date"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Grouped", "Periods Actual"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Periods Missed", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "; "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

[image]